# IBM Worklight 6.0 Application - Page rendering issue in Windows Phone 8 with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, windows-phone-8-emulator, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a simple application in Worklight 6.0 with jquery mobile 1.3.2.

This is an single page application with Header, Content and Footer. Necessary jquery mobile javascript and css files are included.

Given below is the html file from the application.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>DemoApp</title/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png"/>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/DemoApp.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>

    </head>
    <body id="content" style="display: none;">

        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
            <div data-role="content">Content</div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h1>Footer</h1></div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/DemoApp.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have created the Windows Phone 8 Environment and built the worklight project. With the help of Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone the application is launched in windows phone emulator.

[image]

When I scroll the screen I am getting the following response.

[image]
[image]

Please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is fixed header/footer with the content in between scrollable, then try:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
       Content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The tap-toggle setting is to disable hiding the header/footer on tap, but I haven't been able to get JQM fixed headers/footers to behave at all unless I disable it.

I've also found on Windows Phone 8, the footer will position itself too high.  So I have to add the following to the CSS:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
 @-ms-viewport {
    width: 320px;
    user-zoom: fixed;
    max-zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are seeing.  I've taken your HTML and put it n a new WL V6 app.  I modified it to use the non-minified jquery mobile and css (shouldn't matter) added the tap-toggle attributes, added some text in the content so there would be something to scroll, and added the CSS fix above to move the footer down.  Result is that header scrolls, footer stays put, and the app does not switch to half width as shown above.  I'm using WL Studio 6.0.0.2013917-1749 and Visual Studio Express 11.0.60610.01 Update 3

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the app CSS that you are using DemoApp.css. Try disabling the default css in it and running again.

The problem seems to be of the css having been told that the screen size is something bigger than the actual device size.

Regards,
Elvis

Comment: DemoApp.css   a, abbr, address, article, aside, audio, b, blockquote, body, canvas, caption, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, dialog, div, dl, dt, em, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark, menu, nav, object, ol, p, pre, q, samp, section, small, span, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, ul, var, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#content {
height: 460px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 320px;
} I tried removing all default css, still I am getting the same problem.